# chef server version for ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit

Tags: software-center, chef

Where can i get chef-server version for ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit.
this link provided does not have it for 32 bit os,
**http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/**
plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To download the [32Bit](https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/ubuntu/11.04/i686/chef_11.4.4-2.ubuntu.11.04_i386.deb) file.

To install Chef version 11.4.4-2 32bit on Ubuntu 12.04, you need to run the [omnibus installer](http://docs.opscode.com/install_workstation.html)

Before completing the steps described by the omnibus installer, make sure that you install curl:

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl -L http://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

For complete instructions see the [Omnibus Installer](http://docs.opscode.com/install_workstation.html)

Another way of installing chef:  [Take a look at Simple Steps to Install Chef on Ubuntu 12.04](http://generalthings.com/2012/05/08/simple-steps-install-chef-ubuntu-12-04-10-04/)

<sup>Source: [Opscode](http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/)</sup>

Comment: I am getting following log

root@jagdish:/usr/local/bin# curl -L http://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash  
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time 
    Time  Current

                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

100   825  100   825    0     0   2378      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- 

--:--:--  5188
bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `<'
bash: line 1: `<HTML><HEAD>'

Comment: I just tried the same command, and it worked.  Is your Internet connection OK?

Comment: yes, i tried with same, after posting comment that is hidden and shown as link

Comment: So did it work?

Comment: no it didn't, i am behind proxy, what change should there be in command?

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9445489/linux-curl-command-with-proxy), and also the [manpage](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_curl.htm) for curl.  Look at the -x/--proxy option.

Comment: its showing like its downloading, but its stuck for long time, "downloading chef for ubuntu"
do i need to download from there?? what about the link you gave me earlier then, i have downloaded that.

Comment: Look at the info I added in my answer.

Comment: The question is related to how to install Chef Server, not Chef. The instructions in the answer are only to install Chef, not Chef Server.

Comment: @IanD.Rossi  The OP did say that the 32bit version of the server is needed, but according to Chef only a 64bit version is available.  To download that, and for instructions, just click [here](http://www.getchef.com/chef/install/).  Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for *chef-server* on i386 machine.

There has been a documentation bug in Opscode,which has been corrected recently.
[reference](
https://github.com/opscode/chef-docs/commit/fd16e4f5e2d950dc31c75ea53acf417df61a9d90)